# Ubuntu freezes after installation on HP Compaq nx9020 with Intel graphics 855MG

Tags: drivers, system-installation, graphics

I have a HP Compaq nx9020 notebook with Intel graphics 855MG. When I installed Ubuntu 10.04 in text mode everything worked fine, but after a reboot the notebook is freezing after the loading screen with Ubuntu.

Windows works fine so I guess the hardware is ok.

If I use vesa drivers I don't see anything in graphic modes. Console works fine.

How can I sort this out?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in /var/log/Xorg.0.log? You need to look for lines that start with (EE)

Comment: Does the live cd work ok?

Comment: problem in intel chip of i8XX series has been discussed before. http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/2672/blank-screen-on-boot-after-upgrade-from-9-04-to-10-04-with-a-toshiba-tecra-a2-fi unfortunately there in not any proper solution. so i suggest you to switch back to ubuntu 9.10.
I hope they fix this issue in 10.10 release.

Answer (score 2):

Lucky you to have i855.

After selecting your username click the box in the bottom right that says GNOME and switch it to Xterm, then enter the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:glasen/855gm-fix
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install dkms 855gm-fix-dkms
```

Comment: can you explain what those command are doing and what the expected outcome would be?  Adding repositories and packages can break a system or a later upgrade, and should come with sufficient warnings as to what it's doing.